# How to show a specific geometry on the map and hide the others?

Tags: arcobjects, feature-layer

I have a FeatureLayer, i used the method `IFeatureLayer.Search()` and the interface `IQueryFilter` to get a specific Feature, and i want to show only this Feature on the Map, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [IFeatureLayerDefinition Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004v2000000).

> Provides access to members that define a subset of the features from
>   the underlying feature class.

Here is a general code example:

[IFeatureLayerDefinition Example](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/IFeatureLayerDefinition_Example.htm)

Comment: Yeah it works thank you :D but i have another problem i can't zoom to this Feature any tips to do this ?

Comment: @GuebliMohamedAbdessamed I think you should research/ask that as a separate question.